# how to disable external monitors connected to mac book pro without physically disconnecting them

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, macos-catalina, laptop-display

I have 3 external monitors connect to mac book pro .. how ever some time I just want only one monitor, Instead of disconnecting the other two I was looking for a way to disable them , and reenable them when ever I want them without disconnecting them.

Answer (score -1):

You have only two options.

1. Switch them off - this will throw any application windows that were on them back to your primary display.
2. Get a KVM switch & switch the displays away to a second, non-existent, computer. This will allow the Mac to still think they're there & will not return windows to the primary.

Comment: My answer did not apply to your situation so it was incorrect and I deleted it.